# How to fix pygame menu (space invaders)?

Tags: python, menu, pygame

This is my first game so excuse the messy code. I am making a space invaders game and everything i implemented is working fine (sprites, function of the game, music, pause screen, etc). I wanted to implement a really simple menu screen where, if you press C, the game starts. However, the problem with this is that no matter where i call the menu function, there is always a problem, here is the code (im just going to post the menu function and main loop since everything else i believe is not needed).

```
import pygame
import random
import math
from pygame import mixer

# Start pygame
pygame.init()

# Create Screen
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1000, 710))

# Background Image
background = pygame.image.load('background.png').convert_alpha()

# Menu Variables
menu_font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 65)
menuX = 380
menuY = 250

# Menu Function
def game_intro(x, y):
    menu = True
    while menu:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_c:
                    menu = False
                if event.key == pygame.K_q:
                    pygame.quit()
                quit()
    # Menu Text
        menu_text = menu_font.render("Space Invaders", True, (255, 255, 255))
        screen.blit(menu_text, (x, y))

        pygame.display.update()

# Game Loop
running = True
while running:

# RGB - Red, Green, Blue
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))

# Background Image
    screen.blit(background, (0, 0))

----game_intro(menuX,menuY)---IF I PUT IT HERE, THE ACTUAL GAME APPEARS FOR ONE SECOND AND IT GOES BACK TO MAIN MENU-----------

# Making the screen stay still
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

--------game_intro(menuX,menuY)--- IF I PUT IT HERE, THE GAME APPEARS ONLY WHEN 'c' IS BEING HELD DOWN-----------------

*more code*

# Updating
    pygame.display.update()
```

if i put it above pygame.display.update(), then the same thing happens: the game appears for one second and then it goes back to the menu screen. I have tried to search everywhere but the videos either are from 2014, and the websites with some similar problem don't explain how to fix it. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should throw the while loop out of your function.

```
def game_intro(x, y):
    # Menu Text
        menu_text = menu_font.render("Space Invaders", True, (255, 255, 255))
        screen.blit(menu_text, (x, y))
```

the missing code gets put in the mainloop like this

```
...
# Making the screen stay still
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_c:
                menu = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_q:
                pygame.quit()
...
```

now in your mainloop you need to decide whether to draw the menu or the game

```
if menu:
    game_intro(x, y)
else:
    #CODE THAT DRAWS THE GAME
```

all together:

```
import pygame
import random
import math
from pygame import mixer

# Start pygame
pygame.init()

# Create Screen
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1000, 710))

# Background Image
background = pygame.image.load('background.png').convert_alpha()

# Menu Variables
menu_font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 65)
menuX = 380
menuY = 250

# Menu Function
def game_intro(x, y):
    # Menu Text
        menu_text = menu_font.render("Space Invaders", True, (255, 255, 255))
        screen.blit(menu_text, (x, y))

# Game Loop
running = True
while running:

# RGB - Red, Green, Blue
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))

# Background Image
    screen.blit(background, (0, 0))

# Making the screen stay still
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_c:
                menu = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_q:
                pygame.quit()

    if menu:
        game_intro(x, y)
    else:
        # CODE THAT DRAWS THE GAME

# Updating
    pygame.display.update()
```

this should work

note that you need to set `menu` to `True` somewhere to get into the menu

Comment: I have one question, by code that draws the game, you mean like the whole rest of the code?

Comment: Everything that has to do with the actual game like drawing the player, drawing the enemies, collision detection, etc. Because you dont want(and need) that code to be executed when you are in the menu.